# Mat-table not rendering the data saved in ts file on an array of object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

This is my code on a angular material project I am doing to learn Angular Material.

The problem is I am trying to take data from local storage saved earlier in a form, and render it via mat-table. But it doesn't properly render it.

The error: `ERROR Error: "Could not find column with id "name"."`
Clearly I have the name column attribute as I included in the object. I don't understand why this problem is occurring.

```js
export interface Rec {
    name: string;
    cert: string;
    cgpa: number;
}
const record: Rec[] = [] ;

// @title Dialog Overview

@Component({
    selector: 'app-modal',
    templateUrl: 'modal.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['modal.component.scss'],
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}
    recs: Rec[] = [];
    test() {
        record.length = 0;
        if (localStorage.reg) {
            const reg = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reg'));
            // Getting data from two array to one from localstorafe
            for (let index = 0; index < reg.length; index++) {
                const pat = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(reg[index]));
                const patQ = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(reg[index] + 'Q'));
                const data = {
                    name: pat.sal + ' ' + pat.fname + ' ' + pat.lname,
                    cert: patQ.cert1,
                    cgpa: patQ.cgpa1,
                };
                record.push(data);
            }
            this.recs = record;
        }
        console.log(record);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.test();
        console.log(this.recs);
    }

    openDialog() {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Modal);
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- modal.component.html -->
<table mat-table #table [dataSource]="recs">
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="cert">
        <th mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Certification </th>
        <td mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.cert}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="cgpa">
        <th mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> C/GPA </th>
        <td mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.cgpa}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['name', 'cert', 'cgpa']"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['name', 'cert', 'cgpa'];"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample data?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/github/AnupKTarafder/stdt/

Comment: Check the posted answer

Comment: Anup: `{"gender":"m","sal":"Mr.","email":"fake1@gmail.com","phone":"235105616","fname":"Anup","lname":"K Tarafder"}`
AnupQ: `{"cert1":"SSC","cgpa1":5,"cert2":"HSC","cgpa2":"5","cert3":"BSc","cgpa3":"3.2"}`

Comment: I did. I understand your logic, and what you did. But same error persists in my code.

Comment: Solved it. Replaced cdk with mat. Fixed table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own solution after a few hours.

Replaced 'cdk' with 'mat' on every line in the HTML file. The table was rendered perfectly.
*matHeaderCellDef to *cdkHeaderCellDef

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see issue in naming column attributes.
But try below changes and let me know error is still existing.

```
import { MatDialog, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

const record: any = [];

export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}
    recs: any;
    test() {
        record.length = 0;
        if (localStorage.reg) {
            ...
            this.recs = new MatTableDataSource<Rec>(record);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TSlint warning: `Type 'MatTableDataSource<Rec>' is missing the following properties from type 'Rec[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 24 more.`

Comment: Build error: `ERROR in src/app/modal/modal.component.ts(43,13): error TS2322: Type 'MatTableDataSource<Rec>' is not assignable to type 'Rec[]'.  Property 'length' is missing in type 'MatTableDataSource<Rec>'.`

Comment: See my edited answer. I changed `const record: Rec[] = []` to `const record: any = [];`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var data = localStorage.getItem('data'); // Get the data first
if (data) { // If data is available then parse it and assgined as `MatTableDataSource`
  var parsedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
  this.recs = new MatTableDataSource(parsedData);
}
else { // Otherwise set first and then use
  localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(ELEMENT_DATA));
  var parsedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
  this.recs = new MatTableDataSource(parsedData);
}
```

[`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-with-local-storage-cmxeb1)